# probability interpretation of Sturm-Liouville eigenvalue problem

Tags: stochastic-processes, sturm-liouville-theory

For a diffusion process ,  Feymann Kac formula connects the second order elliptic equation.
Look at the eigenvalue problem
$u''-xu'=-\lambda u $, $ u(0)=0,u(1)=0 $. 
for some discrete eigenvalues of $ \lambda $,  the solution is nonzero; for others, the solution is zero.

$ u $ can be viewed as expecation invovling the first passage time $\tau$ escape from $ [0,1] $.
However, from this probabilitic view, how to see the role of the eigenvalues play.

Comment: If $\lambda$ is the first (non zero) eigenvalue of the elliptic operator, you can often relate $\lambda$ to the limiting distribution of the diffusion conditioned not to leave $[0,1]$.

Comment: Alekk:
What limit are you talking about ?  Here the noise is 1,  not small limit.
